# Why is $\overline{f(1/\overline{z})}$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}^{c}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D} = \{z : |z| < 1\}$. Why is $\overline{f(1/\overline{z})}$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}^{c}$?

Comment: Hint: first show that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic in the unit disk, then $f(1/z)$ is holomorphic in the exterior of the unit disk. Then show that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on some domain $\Omega$, then $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1/z$ has a pole only at $z=0$, $1/z$ is analytic in the interior of $\mathbb{D}^c$. Moreover, the image of $(\mathbb{D}^c)^\circ = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| > 1\}$ under $1/z$ is $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$. Thus $f$ is analytic on the range of $1/z$ with this domain. This tells us that $f(1/z)$ is analytic in $(\mathbb{D}^c)^\circ$.

Now suppose that $\bar{z_0} \in (\mathbb{D}^c)^\circ$, which also means $z_0 \in (\mathbb{D}^c)^\circ$. Expand $f(1/z)$ at $\bar{z_0}$: $$f(1/z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-\bar{z_0})^n$$

Thus $$\overline{f(1/\bar{z})} = \sum_{n=0} \bar{a_n}(z-z_0)^n$$

This series has the same radius of convergence as the original unconjugated series. So $\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}$ is analytic at $z_0$. Since $z_0$ was arbitrary in $(\mathbb{D}^c)^\circ$ we have demonstrated analyticity in $(\mathbb{D}^c)^\circ$.